# How to name classes created by OpenAPI Generator and get Map in response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Using OpenApi generator with Spring Boot

Here is my translation.yml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: v0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8088/
    description: Generated server url
paths:
  /api/translation/{module}/{locale}:
    get:
      tags:
        - translations
      summary: Get translations by module, locale and tenantId
      operationId: getTranslations
      parameters:
        - name: module
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: locale
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: tenantId
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Get the translations
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                additionalProperties:
                  type: string
              example:
                nav:
                  payments:
                    invoice:
                      details:
                        title: Payments Details
                        all: AllPayments
                      orders: Orders
                      dashboard: Dashboard
                    title: Payments
                  home:
                    title: Home
```

and here is pom.xml:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/translation.yml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>test.inbound_api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>test.inbound_api.model</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

1. The name of generated interface is `ApiApi.java`. How to generate something like `TranslationApi.java`? **RESOLVED**
2. The generated interface method returns `ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>` how to make it return `ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>`? **RESOLVED**
3. How to correctly provide the `example` with tree structure? In swaggerUi I get now `Example Value "string".` The `example` in my code displayed correctly in Swagger Editor, but not present in the generated interface class. That's what I want to achieve: [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. extend your config options to

```
...
<configOptions>
 <useTags>true</useTags>
 <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
</configOptions>
```

Then the tag will be used to generate the name

2. in your openapi-definition you have currently specified a dictionary that has a `string` as a value. Use

```
additionalProperties:
  type: object
```

to get `ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>`

3. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Maybe the invalid specification in 2. caused this as well?

Comment: If you copy-paste this translation.yml to Swagger Editor you will see the tree structure in the Example Value Schema textarrea. That is what I'm trying to accomplish. It works in Swagger Editor, but not generated in sources.

Comment: 1. and 2. resolved, thanks! But Example still not generated.

Comment: Where do you expect it to be generated? If you want an interface that matches your example, I don't think the generator does that, you'll need to specify a [components/schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) for that

Comment: I just want that it will be displayed in the Swagger UI.

Comment: Looks to me like that's not possible, since the openapi-gernator [does not generate the @ExampleObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887346/the-openapi-generator-maven-plugin-does-not-generate-exampleobject)